# "you don't have permission to edit anything" on custom AdminSite if user is not superuser

Tags: django

I wan't to have multiple AdminSite on my Django project and I don't want to give every user the superuser role just to see and edit the models of the application.

Here is the layout of my project:

```
> djangoApp
    > djangoApp
        - settings.py
        - etc...
    > AAA
        - admin.py
        - urls.py
        - etc..
    > BBB
        - admin.py
        - urls.py
        - etc..
    > CCC
        - admin.py
        - urls.py
        - etc..
    > ressources
        - models.py
        - etc..
    > core
        - admin.py
        - auth.py
        - models.py
        - views.py
```

Here is the admin.py of BBB (I use a different database for each AdminSite):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite, site
from core.admin import UserAuthenticationForm
from ressources.models import Adresse


class BBBAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'BBB admin'

    login_form = UserAuthenticationForm
    login_template = "core/login.html"

    def has_permission(self,request):

        user = request.user

        return user.is_active and user.is_staff and (user.account_id == 100 or user.account_id == 0)

class AdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):

    using = 'DATABASE_NAME'

    def has_add_permission(self, request):

        user = request.user
        return user.is_active and user.is_staff and (user.account_id == 100 or user.account_id == 0)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):

        user = request.user
        return user.is_active and user.is_staff and (user.account_id == 100 or user.account_id == 0)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):

        user = request.user
        return user.is_active and user.is_staff and (user.account_id == 100 or user.account_id == 0)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        user = request.user
        obj.account_id = user.account_id
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(AdminModel, self).get_queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(AdminModel, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(AdminModel, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

bbbAdmin = BBBAdminSite(name='bbbAdmin')


bbbAdmin.register(Adresse, AdminModel) ### The user can see this in the admin dashboard only if he is superuser
```

Here is the urls.py of the same app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from BBB.admin import bbbAdmin


urlpatterns = [
    path('', bbbAdmin.urls),
]
```

I use a different AuthBackend to authenticate my users:

core/auth.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from .models import User

class AuthBackend(object):

def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
    if(obj != None):
        return (obj.account_id == user_obj.account_id)
    return False

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def authenticate(username=None, password=None, account_id=None):

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username, account_id=account_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    pwd_valid = check_password(password, user.password)

    if pwd_valid:
        return user
    else:
        return None
```

I have registered the AuthBackend in my settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('core.auth.AuthBackend',)
```

I tried to change it to:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('core.auth.AuthBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

But it gives me the error

> You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.

I have tried to put the user in a group which had all the permissions, but it still displays "you don't have permission to edit anything" when he logins.
The user has is_staff set to True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution.
I forgot to add the method "has_module_permission" to my AdminModel

BBB/admin.py

```
class AdminModel(Admin.ModelAdmin):

    [...]

    def has_module_permission(self,request):
        return True

    [...]
```

Comment: Still very useful today, thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

For me, I created a custom admin site and made the mistake of initializing it in multiple places, to resolve this, initialize your admin site only once in a variable like so:

```
custom_admin_site = CustomAdminSite()
```

preferably in the same file, it was declared, Then import the variable holding that instance anywhere it needs to be used like in the urls.py for registering the `custom_admin_site.urls` and in for registering your models across apps.
Initializing it somewhere else is creating a whole new admin site and not the same one you initialized earlier, hence the no permission error.

Comment: Good catch, this resolves my custom admin issue